# Dynamically created column heights

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am creating a collection of columns dynamically like shown:

```
  <div *ngFor="let col of colList">
    <corp-column [xs]="'12'" [sm]="'6'">
      <div class="tile tile-default">
        <div class="tile-heading">
          <strong  style="margin-right:5px">{{col.header}}</strong>
        </div>
        <hr style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px">
        <div class="tile-body">
          <div *ngFor="let b of col.body">
            <p>{{b}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </corp-column>
  </div>
```

However, the heights can vary across each column. Like shown below:

https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/woohoo-stack/Capture.PNG

How can I make the each "row" have the same height as it's neighbor?

Comment: add h-100 class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.row-eq-height` bootstrap class, but you must take in consideration the compatibility with browser since it's using flex box.

more details [here](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/)